# Cant create table for some reason MySQL

Tags: mysql

I can't create a table for some reason and I just keep getting the following error.

ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'onesec.students' (errno: 121)

```
create table students (
        student_id int not null,
        fname varchar(34),
        lname varchar(34),
        unitid int,
    lectid int,
        primary key (lectid),
        constraint unitFK foreign key (unitid) references units(unitid),
    constraint lectFK foreign key (lectid) references lecturers(lectid));
```

Anyone knows why? help would be appreciated thanks.

Sorry guys heres the other two tables

```
create table unit (
unitid int primary key,
unit_name varchar(34));

create table lecturers (
    lectid int not null,
    fname varchar(34),
    lname varchar(34),
    unitid int,
    primary key (lectid),
    constraint unitFK foreign key (unitid) references units(unitid);
```

Comment: You Forget to add the error message!

Comment: Please Show the create Statements for your other tables `units`  and `lecturers` too.

Comment: okay added the two tables thanks

Comment: If it is not a type in your question your table Name is different in create table and foreign key diffenition."units" != "unit"